# Pressure in a fluid at rest

Tags: homework-and-exercises, pressure, fluid-statics, stress-energy-momentum-tensor, continuum-mechanics

I hope this is the right place to post such a question. I'm studying Continuum Mechanics from Gurtin's book, and so far in my class we've seen Cauchy's the about the existence of stress, and nothing about fluids yet. I know this exercise is easy, but all I know so far is Cauchy's thm and I am supposed to use it only.

> Let $B$ a body immersed in a fluid at rest, under the action of gravity. Assume that the stress tensor $T$ is a pressure, i.e. by $T= - \pi I$. Determine the pressure field $\pi$.

First of all, I can write the equation of motion: $\operatorname{div}(T)  +b-\rho \dot v =0$

Since the body is at rest, $v=0$. Also, the only body force acting on the system is the gravity, so $b= \rho g$. I'd say that the equation becomes

$$\operatorname{div}(- \pi I) + \rho g =0$$

but now I don't know how to solve this for $\pi$. Any hint or help is highly appreciated.

---

**EDIT**

By expanding the divergence of $- \pi I$, I found:

$$- \frac{\partial \pi }{\partial x_1} = 0$$
$$- \frac{\partial \pi }{\partial x_2} = 0$$
$$- \frac{\partial \pi }{\partial x_3} + \rho g=0$$

and from the last one I have $\pi(x_1,x_2,x_3)=+\rho g x_3$ which indeed has the dimensions of a surface force density, as expected.

Is this correct?

Comment: Buoyancy is not present?  Or is that included in your $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{T}$?

Comment: I think it's not present, because so far we've not talked about fluids and buoyancy @honeste_vivere